# <f:viewParam> not setting value to bean

Tags: jsf-2.2, viewparams

I want to implement a simple PRG approach which for some reason is not working as per my expectation. Please help.

1) I do a POST from firstpage.xhtml

```
                <p:column>
                    <p:menuButton value="#{i18n['actions']}">
                        <p:menuitem value="#{i18n['edit-course']}" icon="ui-icon-pencil" ajax="false" 
                            action="#{courseDesignerBackingBean.navigateToEditCourse(course.courseId)}" />
                        <p:menuitem value="#{i18n['delete-course']}" icon="ui-icon-trash" ajax="false"/>
                    </p:menuButton>
                </p:column>
```

2) Here, I am handling the action and making redirect.

> ```
> public String navigateToEditCourse(long courseId){
>   String outcome = "editCourse?faces-redirect=true" + "&amp;courseId=" + courseId;
>   System.out.println(outcome);
>   return outcome;
> }
> ```

3) In page editCourse.xhtml, I am reading the request parameters.

> ```
> <f:metadata>
>   <f:viewParam name="courseId" value="#{courseModelBean.courseId}"/>
>   <f:event listener="#{courseDesignerBackingBean.updateModelBeanByCourseId}" type="preRenderView"/>
> </f:metadata>
> ```

My expectation on 3rd step was that first setCourseId() of courseModelBean would have got called followed by courseDesignerBackingBean.updateModelBeanByCourseId. But, setCourseId() of courseModelBean is not getting called.

Any hints?

Best regards,
Anand.

Comment: Replacing `&amp;` by `&` in 2) will probably help.

Comment: @BalusC Something like following: <f:view><f:metadata>.....</f:metadata><h:head/><h:body>.....</h:body></f:view>

Comment: @BalusC One more point to add, which might be vital: These views are part of JSF Portlet on Liferay Portal. Do you think it might be some problem with Liferay Faces Bridge? If yes, do you have any other suggestions to make parameterized regquests from PrimeFaces <menuitem> to another view?

Comment: @BalusC: Its exact representation . I am not using <ui:composition> in this view.